# Are these moss? How to prevent?

Tags: roof, moss, slate

Are the spots inside the red circles moss?

Is zinc strip on slate roof a good idea to prevent moss? Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you are going to ask about something in a picture, then make sure the area of interest fills much, much more that 1% of the image

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @jsotola If you click the image twice, it will change to the high resolution version. I intentionally keep the full photo to provide some context information, e.g. surrounding environment and possible moss around, and they might be helpful clue for someone willing to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photos 2 and 3 look more like lichen than moss.  The first one might be moss.
The easiest solution is to ignore it.  It's harmless.